# Client computer(browser) properties in PageLoad

Tags: asp.net, browser, settings, httprequest

Can I know client computer(browser) properties such as screen width when page requests? I need it beckause I dont want to use jquery on client side to set neccesary changes adopting to client browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no; without some client information wrangling, you can not get information such as screen size from the browser. `PageLoad` would basically give you access to the basic request information, none of which will contain any information about browser/window size unless you have had client script collect and submit such information